# Can you use skylanders giants on the new swap force?

Tags: skylanders

Can you use skylanders giants on the new swap force game? Also do we even need them for the new game?

Answer (score 2):

yes, in a review done by Good Game on their Good Game SP show, they showed a clip of one of the Giants approaching one of the 2 elemental gates and showing so that would mean it's possible however it seems just from the review the game is designed just for Swap Force characters with a lot of area's locked even for the basic character

[Good Game SP - Skylanders Swap Force Review](http://www.abc.net.au/abc3/goodgamesp/transcripts/s3877201.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Swap Force is [backward-compatible](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/activision-unveils-new-skylanders/1100-6403426/) with all figures from the previous games: Skylanders Spyro's Adventure and Skylanders Giants.

Giants are not necessary to complete Swap Force.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they work, but not with Spyro's Adventure.