# Can non-giant figures from Skylanders: Giants be used on Skylanders: Swap Force?

Tags: skylanders-giants, skylanders-swap-force

Just started my boys on Skylanders: Giants, they have tons of the figurines, but I noticed there's a new game (Skylanders: Swap Force) and don't know if we have to start over with the figurines? Or can we use old ones to play the new game?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141668/can-you-use-skylanders-giants-on-the-new-swap-force

Answer (score 3):

You can use all the previous Skylander figures with *Skylanders: Swap Force*.

This includes figures from the original *Skylanders*, as well as normal ones, and giants from *Skylanders: Giants*.

This compatability also includes the level packs, powerups, sidekicks, etc. (h/t @JohnoBoy)

Comment: Every figure is forward compatible, including characters, level packs, powerups, sidekicks, etc.